# Spanning set of $V$ with $\dim V$ elements is a basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm following Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra book and using it's theorems.

By using the following theorems and colloraries

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was able to prove that, **for a finite-dimensional vector space $V$**, "*Any linearly independent set of vectors with $\dim V$ elements is a basis for $V$*". That's what i did:

Let $S$ be a linearly independent set with $\dim V$ elements. Assume towards contradiction that $S$ is not a basis for $V$. Then $S$ doesn't span $V$, which means there is $v \in V$ such that $v \notin S$. However, adding $v$ to $S$ results in a linearly independent set with $\dim V + 1$ elements, which is a contradiction because any set with $\gt \dim V$ elements is linearly dependent.

I'm now trying to show that "*Any spanning set of $V$ with $\dim V$ elements is a basis for $V$*".

Basically, I've considered a spanning set $S$ of $V$ with $\dim V$ and I'm trying to prove that it has to be a linearly independent set, but i cannot find how.

I'd really aprecciate any help.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to say $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space in my proof. I'm going to fix that.

Comment: **Hint:** If you have a linearly dependent spanning set, then it is possible to remove an element from the set but keep the same span.

Comment: @BenGrossmann But in this case I wouldn't even consider removing an element from the spanning set, because by Corollary 2 (b) I already now this new set could not span $V$

Comment: Which is exactly how you arrive at a contradiction

Comment: OMG! I just realized. So obvious, thanks.